# In how many ways can 4 letters be chosen from the word TANGENT?

Tags: combinatorics

From a text book , the answer to this question is $5C4$. Why is this? Isn't the answer to be determined by examining all possible combinations of the groups TT and NN and AGE, which would give a number larger than $5$?

Comment: From the answer your provide, the question must imply that you're not allowed to have repeated letters.

Comment: Indeed, an answer of $\binom{5}{4}=5$ makes sense if the question says "in how many ways can 4 **distinct** letters be chosen from the word TANGENT."  If we allow repetition, break it into cases: (no repeated, 2T no other repeated, 2N no other repeated, 2T and 2N) for a total of $\binom{5}{4}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{4}{2}+1 = 18$

Answer (score 1):

You have 5 letters. The repetition of the letters is meaning less for the question asked. So the answer is all the possibilities of selecting 4 out of 5 when the order is not important.